# Conditional Formatting Excel Based On Date In Another Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I looked through everything re conditional formatting, but nothing touched on my issue.

I am trying to highlight cells in a column based on the date in another cell, as well as the text in the cell in question. I have been able to do both parts separately as basic conditional formatting, but not sure how to have it all work as one using a formula.

`A1` has the text and `D1` has the date. If the date is today and the text is either 2 or 3, I want the cell to be coloured using conditional formatting.

Here is the formula I tried for conditional formatting, but with no result:-

```
=IF(AND($D1=TODAY(), OR(A1="3", A1="2")))
```

Basically, if the date in `D1` is today and `A1` is either a 2 or 3, then apply the conditional formatting. Seems simple, but I can only get it working as separate parts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

## Just 'Imagine' IF in Conditional Formatting

- Every date in Excel is actually a number, e.g. for `27.01.2019` it is
  `43492`. You can format a cell containing a date, as number, and see
  for yourself.
- When there is time with a date, there is additionally a
  decimal part, e.g. for `27.01.2019 14:52:17` the number would be
  approximately `43492.6196`, which is different than `43492`.

Therefore you have to use the `INT` function to round the number down to the nearest integer resulting in the following **conditional formatting formula**:

> ```
> =AND(INT(D1)=TODAY(),OR(A1="FA_Win_3",A1="FA_Win_2"))
> ```

used e.g. for cell `E1`.

- So the logic behind the formula could be interpreted: (just imagine
  the `IF`): `IF` the rounded down value of cell `D1` is equal to
  `TODAY`'s value (date) `AND` the value in cell `A1` is `EITHER` `FA_Win_3` `OR` `FA_Win_2`, **DO** apply the formatting (, or else **don't**).

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
=IF(AND($D1=TODAY(), OR($A$1=3, $A$1=2)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Or

```
=AND($D1=TODAY(), OR($A$1=3, $A$1=2))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Harun. The problem appears to be in the date format, which is date and time (d/m/yyyy hh:mm). That needs to remain formatted that way. It's odd, as when I just do a basic conditional format using the date (no formula needed), that part of it works fine, but to include the other criteria requires a formula and with that, it doesn't seem to be able to decipher 27/1/2019 19:30 as just a date. Any ideas how to tell Excel how to read the date? Thanks again

Comment: If the cell is formatted with date and value is `27/1/2019 19:30` then it will not be an issue. It will work fine. If `27/1/2019 19:30` is entered as text then you need to apply few date formula to tell excel read as date.

Comment: Hello Harun. I don't believe it is possible to have the cell formatted as Date and have the time in there as well, unless you know a way. They are all formatted as Custom with d/m/yyyy hh:mm as the format. Neither of the formulas work with the date as is. If I delete any numbers from the time, so it reads 00:00, then the second formula works. Chers

Answer (score 0):

I’m not in front a computer, but you can try this:

```
=AND(TEXT($B2,"dd/mm/yyyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), OR(A1="FA_Win_3", A1="FA_Win_2"))
```

---

If you have trouble with users pasting over the cells and messing up with the conditional format, you can add this soubroutine to the worksheet.

To add it:
 - Press F11
 - Double click the sheet name
 - Copy paste the code
 - Read the comments inside the code and adapt it to fit your needs
 - Save the workbook as macro-enabled

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' This method has a drawback and is that the undo feature in this sheet no longer works (if you can live with it, no problem)
    ' Here is an option to bring it back: https://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA04.asp

    ' Define variables
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim formulaEval As String

    ' Define the Range where they paste the date. This is the range that receives the conditional format
    Set targetRange = Range("B2:B70")

    ' Define the formula evaluated by the conditional format (replace ; for ,)
    formulaEval = "=AND(TEXT(" B2 ",""dd/mm/yyyy"")=TEXT(TODAY(),""dd/mm/yyyy""), OR(A" 2 "=""FA_Win_3"", A" 2 "=""FA_Win_2""))"

    If Not Intersect(Target, targetRange) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=formulaEval
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

            ' This is where the format applied is defined (you can record a macro and replace the code here)
            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

---

> Please mark this answer if it helped you

Comment: cheers Ricardo, but that doesn't do the trick. In fact the conditional formatting area will not even accept it as a formula. cheers

Comment: OK, so I had to replace the ” in your formula with a normal ". This means each cell in column A is coloured, not just the ones with a 2 or 3 in them. At least it is reading the date correctly

Comment: Ah, solved I think. I removed the absolute cell reference for $A$1 and made it A1, as this is for all cells in column A. It now seems to behave as it should, which is great. Thanks so much

Comment: I may have spoken too soon, Ricardo. Using the numbers 2 & 3 was really just to get the formula to work. The actual text in the cells in the real sheet is FA_Win_2 & FA_Win_3. The formula appeared to be working fine with those original numbers 2 or 3, which was a test sheet, but not when they are changed to what is in the actual sheet the formula is to be used for.  Thoughts why it would stop working based on this changed cell content=AND(TEXT($D1,"dd/mm/yyyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), OR(A1=FA_Win_3, A1=FA_Win_2)) As you can see, the only changes are 2 to FA_Win_2 and 3 to FA_Win_3

Comment: You may have to enclose the strings with quote signs. I've updated the code in the answer to correct the quote signs and enclose the values that the A1 should compare to. Please try again.

Comment: H Ricardo; yep, absolutely nailed it. Thanks so much. It's perfect. Take care

Comment: Great honkin. can please mark this as answered. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Ricardo, there's been a bit of a hitch and I am unsure what to do, as that formula was terrific. Let me explain.

The file has data input by various people; data added from other files and other worksheets. My aim was to conditionally format the column A so that when that text I indicated, FA_Win_2 or FA_Win_3 is there and the cell next door, column B, was today's date, that it highlighted. 

Everything worked fine when I simply input the formula into the conditional formatting area.

Comment: The next day, when someone copied and pasted data from other sources into cells in column A and added dates in column B, then things got messy. and cells were being highlighted that were referencing the date in a cell not adjacent. In fact, on going back into the Manage Rules area of the conditional formatting area, there were now two rules and neither covered all the cells in column A, so the results were all over the place.

Comment: So my question to resolve this is, how to protect cells in column A so the conditional formatting remains for the entire column, but allow people to copy and paste data from other sources? Is it even possible?

Thanks so much, Ricardo and sorry this has gotten a bit messy

Comment: Hi Honkin, are you allowed to use Macros or able to change the workbook and save it as macro enabled?

Comment: Absolutely Ricardo. I am the author of the document and the other contributors merely add data into specific cells, so no issue to use macros

Comment: I've just updated the answer with VBA code that may help you.

Comment: hi Ricardo
My apologies for the delay. I have never worked with the VBE before, so am experimenting to get it right. The formula is returning the message, Compile Error, Expected End Of Statement. Here is the formula line:-

formulaEval = "=AND(TEXT(" B1 ",""dd/mm/yyyy"")=TEXT(TODAY(),""dd/mm/yyyy""), OR(A" 1 "=""FA_Win_2"","A" & Target.Row & "=""FA_Win_3""))"

I left the space in that you had and just replaced the words " & Target.Address & " with " B1 " and the words A" & Target.Row & " with A" 1 " We are looking for the date B1 to be today's date and the text to be either of above

Comment: I was also unsure with the color code.....just a hex code? I used the full hex code of 00B050 and it did not like that.

Comment: I changed the color format to all RGB and seems to be no errors showing. This is what is in the format section

' This is where the format applied is defined (you can record a macro and replace the code here)
            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
.Font.Bold = True

Basically just a green cell with white text in bold